# Android: Adding many children to a layout in a separate thread

Tags: android, multithreading, layout, children

I have an activity with a Button and a GridLayout with many children. If I add all these children in onCreate() my activity appears on a screen with a lag:

```java
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    LinearLayout main = new LinearLayout(this);
    main.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

    Button button = new Button(this);
    button.setText("test");
    main.addView(button);

    GridLayout testGrid = new GridLayout(this);
    testGrid.setColumnCount(5);
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        testGrid.addView(new Button(this));
    main.addView(testGrid);

    setContentView(main);
}
```

But I want at least my Buttton to appear immediately, so I try to add the children to the grid in a thread. After experiments I came to this solution:

```java
    final GridLayout testGrid = new GridLayout(this);
    testGrid.setColumnCount(5);
    main.addView(testGrid);
    Handler handler = new Handler();
    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            new Thread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
                        MyActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                testGrid.addView(new Button(testGrid.getContext()));
                            }
                        });
                }
            }).start();
        }
    }, 1);
```

But I'm not sure it's a good idea, because it looks kinda complicated and may be it won't work well on some devices. Any better suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

When you have to do something like this, it is a clear indication that you do something wrong. If you really need 100 buttons in a grid, maybe you should consider using GridView instead of GridLayout and loading buttons into view via a simple adapter.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, but I don't want to use GridView because it has some lags when scrolling.